# Map Reduce code for pipe separated multiline unstructured data

Tags: java, hadoop

I have multiline unstructured data separateted with a pipe ( `||` ) as shown below:

```
||
nokia,111,55000,uk,20160809,109
100,online,credit,
10%,90%,2015
||
iphone,6,60000,USA,20160809,110,
100,online,credit
||
samsung,s7,60000,USA,20160809,110
100,online,credit
||
..... millions of records ....
```

The first record is 3 lines, the next record is 2 lines, so the number of lines are not constant. Please tell me how to process this data using `Map Reduce 2`, custom input split & custom Record reader. Any links & blogs are also appreciated.

Please tell me of any errors in my `Custom Record Reader` class below:

```
public class CustomInputFormat extends FileInputFormat<LongWritable,Text>{ 
    @Override
    public RecordReader<LongWritable,Text> createRecordReader(InputSplit    split,TaskAttemptContext context) {
        return new CustomRecordReader();
    }

public class CustomRecordReader extends RecordReader<LongWritable, Text> {
    private long start;
    private long pos;
    private long end;
    private LineReader in;
    private int maxLineLength;
    private LongWritable key = new LongWritable();
    private Text value = new Text();

    private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(CustomRecordReader.class);

    @Override
    public void initialize(InputSplit genericSplit, TaskAttemptContext context)     throws IOException {

        FileSplit split = (FileSplit) genericSplit;
        Configuration job = context.getConfiguration();
        this.maxLineLength = job.getInt("mapred.linerecordreader.maxlength",
                Integer.MAX_VALUE);

        start = split.getStart();
        end = start + split.getLength();
        final Path file = split.getPath();
        FileSystem fs = file.getFileSystem(job);
        FSDataInputStream fileIn = fs.open(split.getPath());
        boolean skipFirstLine = false;

        if (start != 0) {
            skipFirstLine = true;
            --start;
            fileIn.seek(start);
        }
        in = new LineReader(fileIn, job);
        if (skipFirstLine) {
            Text dummy = new Text();
            start += in.readLine(dummy, 0,
                    (int) Math.min((long) Integer.MAX_VALUE, end - start));
        }
        this.pos = start;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean nextKeyValue() throws IOException {
        int newSize = 0;
        while (pos < end) {
            newSize = in.readLine(value);
            if (newSize == 0) break;
            pos += newSize;
            key.set(pos);
            if(value.toString().equals("||"))
                LOG.info("Skipped line of size " + newSize + " at pos "
                + (pos - newSize));
            else
                break;
        }
        if (newSize == 0)
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public LongWritable getCurrentKey() throws IOException,
            InterruptedException {
        return key;
    }

    @Override
    public Text getCurrentValue() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public float getProgress() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        if (start == end) {
            return 0.0f;
        } else {
            return Math.min(1.0f, (pos - start) / (float) (end - start));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        if (in != null) {
            in.close();
        }
    }
}


public class CustomMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, CustomInputFormat, LongWritable, CustomInputFormat>{
    final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    @Override
    protected void map(LongWritable key, CustomInputFormat value, org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        System.out.println(" *** Key is: "+key+" value is: "+value+" *** ");
        if(null!=value ){
                   context.write(key, value);
        }
    }
}


public class CustomDriver extends Configured {  
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception  {      
        if(args.length!=2){
            System.out.println("pls give i/p & o/p direc");
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        Job job = new Job();        
        job.setJarByClass(CustomDriver.class);
        Configuration conf=job.getConfiguration();                      
        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

        job.setMapperClass(CustomMapper.class);

        job.setInputFormatClass(CustomInputFormat.class);

        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(LongWritable.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(CustomInputFormat.class);        

        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true)?0:-1);
    }
}
```

I am getting below error on running:

```
[cloudera@quickstart gous]$ hadoop jar c3.jar com.ownUnstruct.CustomDriver /user/mr/custom /user/mr/out
16/04/18 23:15:01 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
16/04/18 23:15:02 WARN mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Hadoop command-line option parsing not performed. Implement the Tool interface and execute your application with ToolRunner to remedy this.
16/04/18 23:15:02 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
16/04/18 23:15:02 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
16/04/18 23:15:02 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1461045457615_0001
16/04/18 23:15:03 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1461045457615_0001
16/04/18 23:15:03 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://quickstart.cloudera:8088/proxy/application_1461045457615_0001/
16/04/18 23:15:03 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1461045457615_0001
16/04/18 23:15:15 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1461045457615_0001 running in uber mode : false
16/04/18 23:15:15 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
16/04/18 23:15:22 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1461045457615_0001_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.io.IOException: Initialization of all the collectors failed. Error in last collector was :null
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.createSortingCollector(MapTask.java:414)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.access$100(MapTask.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewOutputCollector.<init>(MapTask.java:698)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:770)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1671)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.init(MapTask.java:1011)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.createSortingCollector(MapTask.java:402)
    ... 9 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the pipe symbol is always preceded and followed by a newline character, I don't think there is a need for custom input split or custom record reader. You can write the code for mapper as follows:

```
public class MyMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {

    private Text textValue;

    @Override
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        //process the data
    }

    @Override
    public void run(Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text>.Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        setup(context);
        textValue = new Text();
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        while (context.nextKeyValue()) {
            String line = context.getCurrentValue().toString();
            if(line.equals("||")){
                textValue.set(sb.toString());
                if(!("".equals(sb.toString())))
                    map(context.getCurrentKey(), textValue, context);
                sb = new StringBuffer();
            } else {
                sb.append(line);
            }   
        }
        cleanup(context);
    }
}
```

This should get you started with your processing.

**UPDATE:** Change your code in `nextKeyValue()` to something like this and give it a try.

```
@Override
public boolean nextKeyValue() throws IOException {
    int newSize = 0;
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    while (pos < end) {
        newSize = in.readLine(value);
        if (newSize == 0) break;
        pos += newSize;
        key.set(pos);
        if(value.toString().equals("||")){
            LOG.info("Skipped line of size " + newSize + " at pos "
                + (pos - newSize));
            break;
        } else
            sb.append(value.toString());
    }
    value.set(sb.toString());
    if (newSize == 0)
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

**UPDATE:** Change you mapper to something like this:

```
public class CustomMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, LongWritable, Text>{
    @Override
    protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) 
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        System.out.println(" *** Key is: "+key+" value is: "+value+" *** ");
        if(null!=value ){
           context.write(key, value);
        }
    }
}
```

And in the `CustomDriver` class, change the following line

```
job.setMapOutputValueClass(CustomInputFormat.class);
```

to

```
job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
```

Comment: Hey Johnson Charles thanks for your help, can you please go thru my code & let me know any correction ?

Comment: First i would like to appreciate ur effort in providing me the solution. Yes i was expecting output as:
65 nokia,111,55000,uk,20160809,109,100,online,credit,10%,90%,2015  <br>
116 iphone,6,60000,USA,20160809,110,100,online,credit

Comment: Hey Johnson Charles, i have added your method nextKeyValue() in CustomRecordRecord & i am getting the error as reported above. The code above is a fresh code with ur suggested changes. Please can you suggest any changes ?

Comment: There is still a NullPointerException. Is that the complete stack trace you have?

Comment: Yes, its the complete stack trace. If possoble can you please execute  ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have the setup to execute this. However, your mapper signature is not correct. I already updated the answer. Try with that and see if it fixes your issue.

Comment: Ok, Thank you for your help. I will execute it in next 4 hours & will let you know. A lot of thanks.

Comment: Hi Charles,i am getting this wrong output


35 nokia,111,55000,uk,20160809,109
54 100,online,credit,
67 10%,90%,2015
103 iphone,6,60000,USA,20160809,110,
121 100,online,credit
158 samsung,s7,60000,USA,20160809,110
176 100,online,credit
179 ||

                                                                                                                                       
Expected output:
65 nokia,111,55000,uk,20160809,109,100,online,credit,10%,90%,2015
116 iphone,6,60000,USA,20160809,110,100,online,credit

Comment: Are you using the custom reader? If so that's what you get. You should merge the logic I've in my mapper to the reader code. Do you want me to change the reader?

Comment: Thats done, i got the desired output Charles. Great.
Is this called data cleansing ? because this cleaned data can now be uploaded to HIVE tables in hadoop

70 nokia,111,55000,uk,20160809,109100,online,credit,10%,90%,2015
124 iphone,6,60000,USA,20160809,110,100,online,credit
179 samsung,s7,60000,USA,20160809,110100,online,credit

Comment: I don't know if there is a specific name to it but this kind of processing is quite common with MapReduce. I'm glad it worked for you.